# Plot Min, Max, Average, Median values into a horizontal enumerated line in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I am trying to do a trivial task with Power BI Desktop. I have the following kind of data

```
| Name      | Min   | Max       | Average   | Median    |
|--------   |-----  |-------    |---------  |--------   |
| team A    | 0     | 3,817     | 120       | 120       |
| team B    | -10   | 1,050     | 25        | 89        |
| team C    | 5     | 14,320    | 50        | 48        |
```

And I want to create my own horizontal line with pre-defined (Start, End) points to plot for each team name the values of the *Min, Max, Average, Median*. And I filter the team name to adjust the numbers and the visual accordingly.

So far I have done the following **static** approach

[image]

The example above is totally non-dynamic because every point on the line is set by me. Also if for example, I select Team B with a higher median than average then the above visual line does not change the position of the relative spheres (in the image I posted, I have placed average always higher than the median which is not true for all the teams).

Thus, I would like to know if there is any fancy and well-plotted way to represent those 4 descriptive measures for a team name in a horizontal line that will respond when I use a different team. As I have noted on the image attached, the card visuals change when I change the team name. But the spheres do not move across the line.

My desired output

For Team B

[image]

While for Team C

[image]

I literally don't know if this is feasible in Power BI apart from the static approach I already did. Thank you in advance.

Regards.